# Changing the number of interneurons in Dense

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am novice in tensorflow and keras. I have the code below but I do not know why when I change 1 in dense to 10 (Dense(10)) I get error. I think I should be able to arbitrarily change the number of neurons in each layer. How should I change the number of neurons in dense? and if I want to add more dense latyers is there any rule for the number in dense?

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1029, input_dim=29))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
#odel.add(Dropout (0.2))



sgd=SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(input, target, steps_per_epoch=4, epochs=1000)
```

error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_65 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and I will post here for who might face the same issue. Th reason is that I need to have the last layer number of neurons equal to 1 according to my output. My input dimension is 1029 rows and 29 columns and my target is 1029 rows. I can add another layers of dense with arbitrary number of neurons.